# Rollback within trigger for one row when multiple rows are in inserted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, database-trigger

I have a table 'TEST' with some columns. Columns 'VALIDATED' and 'DELETED' are bit values

```
 TEST Table:
    Id      VALIDATED     DELETED
     1           0          0
     2           0          0
     3           1          0
     4           0          0
     5           1          0
     6           0          0
```

Id is an INT value and primary key.

I have created below trigger for this table and for column 'DELETED' only when it is updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MY_TRIGGER]   
   ON  [dbo].[TEST] 
   FOR UPDATE 
AS 
IF UPDATE([DELETED])
BEGIN

DECLARE @Id INT;

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT (I.Id)
FROM INSERTED I;

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE Id = @Id AND VALIDATED = 1)
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 
                     FROM DELETED D INNER JOIN INSERTED I
                       ON D.Id = I.Id
                    WHERE D.Id = @Id AND D.[DELETED] = 0 
                          AND I.[DELETED] = 1)

        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('CANNOT DELETE!' ,10, 1);
            ROLLBACK
        END
    END


   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id
END  

 CLOSE      db_cursor;
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
END
```

Now I perform below update statement:

```
Update TEST
SET    DELETED=1
```

Above trigger avoid to mark as deleted a row that is already validated.
When a row is validated and I am trying to mark it as deleted then a rollback is done.

My doubt is:
Is Roolback being done for all rows being updated? or is rollback done for only  the row being processed.

How can I do the rollback only for the row which raise the error and commit the rest?

Comment: You have 3 variables in the above trigger, Id, Process_ID and Process. So, I'm not sure if this trigger is even working.

Comment: You do NOT need a cursor here. You can do this as a set based query with no issue at all. And a rollback rolls back the ENTIRE transaction, not a single row. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Correct. I have corrected it. It was an error when typing. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of that cursor. It is doing nothing but making this slower and way more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to check each and every row, you only need to see if there is a row being updated that violates your business rule.

Your entire trigger can be reduced to this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MY_TRIGGER]   
   ON  [dbo].[TEST] 
   FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM DELETED D 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON D.Id = I.Id
        WHERE D.[DELETED] = 0 
            AND I.[DELETED] = 1
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('CANNOT DELETE!' ,10, 1);
        ROLLBACK
    END
```